# Reducing code duplication in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a rspec test that contains about 20 ExampleGroups(defined by the 'describe' keyword). Every ExampleGroup contains an 'after' method to be called after each example.

```
describe "grouping" do
  include Common
  after do
    after_example
  end
end
```

In this test, the 'after' method is identical across all 20 ExampleGroups. Currently, I just use a mixin to keep from duplicating the code but it seems redundant to always have to specify the 'after' clause and that it should call the mixin in every single ExampleGroup.

Is there a way to do this so I don't have to specify the 'after' in every ExampleGroup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well being that these example groups all have the same after method, are they somehow related?  Because then you can just nest the groups under a parent.

```
describe "parent grouping" do
  include Common
  after do
    after_example
  end

  describe "child 1" do
    pending
  end

  describe "child 2" do
    pending
  end

  ...
end
```

RSpec will run the parent grouping before/after for the children blocks and have the mixin available to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write your module so that it automatically adds the after block:

```
module Common
  def included(base)
    base.after do
      # add shared "after" logic here
    end
  end
end

describe 'a spec' do
  include Common
  # no need to add the after logic, since it got added on 'include'
end
```